# Is it possible to have multiple URL connections in JAVA?

Tags: java, connection

I'm having some trouble getting URL connection to work. I find that if I create one URL object it works fine. But everything after that doesn't work at all. At first I thought it could have been due to me not closing a stream but that was not the case.

-1 = Failure

1 = success

```
Testing:
        URLFail test0 = new URLFail();
        URLFail test1 = new URLFail(1);
        URLFail test2 = new URLFail(1,1);

OutPut:
    0Param  1
    1Param -1
    2Param -1
```

Now if i switch which object gets create first the results change.

```
Testing:
        URLFail test2 = new URLFail(1,1);
        URLFail test0 = new URLFail();
        URLFail test1 = new URLFail(1);

OutPut:
      0Param -1
      1Param -1
      2Param  1
```

In this instance only test2 succeeded. This leads me to believe that only one URL stream can be used per class?

This is what i've been using to access and parse the URL.

```
        URL url = null;
        URLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("xxxxx"); // In my program this is a proper URL

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            return -1;
        }

        ArrayList<String> index = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            while (in.ready()) {
                index.add(in.readLine());
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return -1;

        }
```

So far I don't really know what's wrong. I think it could be due to the fact that I'm trying to access the same website too fast?

I've also tried without a URLConnection object by using the openStream() method found in URL. Any help will be appreciated, also any general comments about the code itself are welcomed as well. Thanks!

This is the Entire Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class URLFail {
    private int name;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        URLFail test0 = null;
        URLFail test1 = null;
        URLFail test2 = null;

        try {
            test0 = new URLFail();
            System.out.println("First Complete...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            test2 = new URLFail();
            System.out.println("Second Complete...");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            test1 = new URLFail();
            System.out.println("Third Complete...");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("0Param " + test0.name);
        System.out.println("1Param " + test1.name);
        System.out.println("2Param " + test2.name);

    }

    public URLFail() {
        name = getAsList();
    }

    public int getAsList() {

        URL url = null;
        URLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("xxxxx");
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }

        ArrayList<String> index = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            urlConnection = url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            while (in.ready()) {
                index.add(in.readLine());
            }

            in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return -1;
        }

        if (index.isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }

    }

}
```

I tried this with google.com and it worked fine, so it must be the host that I'm trying to connect to. Is there any way to close a URL connection/disconnect?

Comment: Are they http connections? are they connections to the same server?

Comment: What does the constructor arguments signify? How are they used. Try to post the entire code of URLFail.

Comment: It is an http connection. And the constructors were actually pointless I'm not sure what I was thinking. The whole code is posted now.

Comment: Multiple simultaneous http connections to the same URL may be disallowed on the server side.

Comment: I think that's exactly what's going on. But how do I disconnect?

Comment: You can cast the urlConnection to an HttpURLConnection, and then call disconnect().

Comment: Throw out your current code, and write it again.  Do _not_ use error codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's your behaviour on your "problem" server with the full example code when running it three times in a row? Does it always produce the same result if you run it a couple of times?

Could it be that

```
in.ready()
```

simply returns false the first time it's checked in the loop, because your target server simply doesn't send the response quickly enough?

Comment: This helped a lot. I added a while loop that keeps trying to connect until the stream is ready. Although this doesn't seem like the most efficient way to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would research if the `in.ready()` call is necessary at all. It seems that the underlying input stream of the connection object can block on read by default (with (optional?) timeout).

Answer (score 3):

In front of each "return -1" insert a

```
ex.printStackTrace();
```

This will most likely tell you what you need to know.

Comment: Those errors aren't being called. The -1 comes from a different snippet of code that I didn't include. Basically that error is produced because the new ArrayList is empty, meaning that when I opened a URL stream it had nothing in it.

Comment: Have you considered using _different_ error codes so they actually tell you something useful?

Comment: @Uri Then run it with `ex.printStackTrace()`? It will tell you more about what exactly went wrong, instead of guessing and clairvoyance. ;-)

Comment: @Santa there is no Exception object where the "error" is being thrown. I am simply calling an if statement. If list is empty return -1.

Comment: @Uri So these lines is the originator, then:

`
    if (index.isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
    }
`

Nothing was ever put into `index`, possibly because your while loop never got to execute (because, like weiresr said, the first call to `in.ready()` returned `false`).